# Context Switch Time between two processes and threads in two processes

Tags: multithreading, process, context-switch

So the story goes like this:

Process **1** begins execution at main thread **A**, and little bit after also create process in thread **B**. Same for the process **2**.

If we assume that threads are always ready for execution  and execute one a single CPU machine, sort by the context switch overhead next swithing:

a) 2A -> 1A

b) 2B -> 2A

c) 1B -> 2A

d) 1A -> 1B

Explain your answers.

So, my guess is that you need less time for context switch between two threads, than between two processes.
I think that first letter of answer is d) - because it is context switch between two threads in the SAME process, so you need the smallest amount of time for that.

After that, I assume that 1B -> 2A is next, then 2A -> 1A, and finally 2B -> 2A.

My answers: `d), b), a) and c)`.

Also, here's the picture of how I imagined the situation;

[image: process switching diagram]

Could someone please check this solution and correct me if I am wrong? And also, I am not sure how to explain these other context switches besides 1A -> 1B.

Comment: Please, can anyone check if the solution I posted is correct...